# HP ALM: Get all available requirement types with REST API

Tags: rest, alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

If you want to create a requirement in HP ALM you have to specify the field ''type-id''. Is there a way to get all the available requirement types over the REST API? In all examples I can find, people use hardcoded values but no code to get the right id.

Answer (score 3):

The end-point is:

```
https://****.hp.com/qcbin/rest/domains/DomainName/projects/ProjectName/customization/entities/requirement/types
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give full list of customization done by ALM admin
https://alm12.intranet.db.com/qcbin/rest/domains/{domains}/projects/{project}/customization/used-lists?login-form-required=y

This will give full list of tag available with current installation of ALM
https://alm12.intranet.db.com/qcbin/rest/domains/{domains}/projects/{project}/customization/lists?login-form-required=y

This will give all requirement fields values
https://alm12.intranet.db.com/qcbin/rest/domains/{domains}/projects/{project}/customization/entities/requirement/lists?login-form-required=y

This will give type of requirements supported by ALM version
https://alm12.intranet.db.com/qcbin/rest/domains/{domains}/projects/{project}/customization/entities/requirement/types?login-form-required=y